# OAuth Refresh Token Process for salesforce SDK

Tags: ios, salesforce

Can anyone help me with refreshing token on saleforce.

```
NSDictionary *fields = @{@"grant_type" : @"refresh_token",
                         @"refresh_token": oauth[@"refreshToken"],
                         @"client_id": coordinator.credentials.clientId,
                         @"format": @"json"
                         };
SFRestRequest *request = [SFRestRequest requestWithMethod:SFRestMethodPOST path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/services/oauth2/token",[SFAccountManager loginHost]] queryParams:fields];
request.endpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/services/oauth2/authorize", [SFAccountManager loginHost]];

[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] sendRESTRequest:request failBlock:^(NSError *e) {

    NSLog(@"Error %@", e);

} completeBlock:^(NSDictionary* dict) {

    NSLog(@"dict");

}];
```

This is what i am trying to do, but i am getting the following error:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=404 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 404.)" UserInfo=0x7993c670 {Transfer-Encoding=Identity, Content-Type=text/html;charset=UTF-8, Date=Thu, 13 Nov 2014 15:23:36 GMT}

I am not sure what is going wrong. 
FYI: [Understanding the OAuth Refresh Token Process](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm)

This is the request:

```
endpoint: test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize 
method: POST 
path: test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token 
queryParams: {"grant_type":"refresh_token","refresh_token":"5AsdfdfssdBuiV6yFNukUqDSMUH1tnk39L.x0GFcdqdMhpmQUTu.wv1BNndfglD3SxEZIFUev4i8T2KLkcCOK","format":"json","client_id":"3MVG9dPGzsddfssfdsOQG3p9KW.2hh3Bh5BeEsdfsRlDhxcybG.YRTQC0C0XayvzEw.5.umftLwJpYjYVDE6xgSCgXo"}
```

Comment: Please try in postman first, then post results / screenshots of that.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using Salesforce and NSURL Kit instead i use AFHTTPREQUEST

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:@"password" forKey:@"grant_type"];
    [dict setObject:@"xxx" forKey:@"client_id"];
    [dict setObject:@"xxx" forKey:@"client_secret"];
    [dict setObject:@"your user" forKey:@"username"];
    [dict setObject:@"password" forKey:@"password"];
    [dict setObject:@"json" forKey:@"format"];

[manager POST:@"https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token" parameters:dict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {

    }];
```